# Why is a union of two queries faster than a single one of the unioned queries?

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-sql, postgresql-9.6

I'm debugging query times in 2x Google Cloud SQL Postgres 9.6 instances with Autovacuuming. Staging (no traffic) 7.5gb + 2vCPU. And production: 37.5gb with 10vCPU. The results are the same and confusing.

Indexes:

- trade_user1
- trade_user2

**Consistently 100-120ms:**

```
SELECT * FROM "Trade" WHERE "user1" = 1
UNION
SELECT * FROM "Trade" WHERE "user2" = 1
LIMIT 24;
```

```
Limit  (cost=221.92..222.16 rows=24 width=1187) (actual time=0.115..0.124 rows=24 loops=1)
  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=221.92..222.46 rows=54 width=1187) (actual time=0.115..0.121 rows=24 loops=1)
        Group Key: id, status, user1, user2
        ->  Append  (cost=4.60..218.55 rows=54 width=1187) (actual time=0.024..0.076 rows=26 loops=1)
              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on "Trade"  (cost=4.60..89.99 rows=22 width=155) (actual time=0.024..0.061 rows=23 loops=1)
                    Recheck Cond: (user1 = 1)
                    Heap Blocks: exact=20
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on trade_depositor_user_id  (cost=0.00..4.59 rows=22 width=0) (actual time=0.016..0.016 rows=23 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (user1 = 1)
              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on "Trade" "Trade_1"  (cost=4.67..128.02 rows=32 width=155) (actual time=0.011..0.014 rows=3 loops=1)
                    Recheck Cond: (user2 = 1)
                    Heap Blocks: exact=3
                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on trade_withdrawer_user_id  (cost=0.00..4.67 rows=32 width=0) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=3 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: (user2 = 1)
Planning time: 0.224 ms
Execution time: 0.189 ms
```

**Consistently 280-350ms:**

```
SELECT * FROM "Trade" WHERE "user1" = 1
```

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on "Trade"  (cost=4.60..89.99 rows=22 width=155) (actual time=0.023..0.054 rows=23 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: (user1 = 1)
  Heap Blocks: exact=20
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on trade_user1  (cost=0.00..4.59 rows=22 width=0) (actual time=0.015..0.015 rows=23 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (user2 = 1)
Planning time: 0.077 ms
Execution time: 0.078 ms
```

Both queries return equal result set sizes. I've tried different variations of the simpler query like ordering by ID ASC/DESC.

Comment: the second does not have a `LIMIT 24;`

Comment: Note: you should not compare `0.189 ms` to `0.078 ms`. The figures are too small to be compared. (and there also is cache-warming) And: where does the `Consistently 280-350ms:` figure come from?

Comment: I can add a LIMIT 24 to the second one and it's the same result. The 280-350ms is the full network round trip. It's the number from pgAdmin but if I check Network Requests it's matching up. They're both 12kb responses and the union is MUCH quicker which means there has to be a problem at the database/server

Comment: `which means there has to be a problem at the database/server` No, it is not. 0.1 % of your time is spent by the query, the rest is used by the networkdelay+frontend.

Comment: Interesting side note:By your posted numbers the FAST query spends 0.413ms in database operation while the SLOW query spends 0.155ms in the database operation. Meaning the SLOW query is 2.6645 times faster. Try this; restart server then run queries, restart again run queries in reverse order. Any difference?  Further is this another case of ability to measure extremely short time intervals, but *complete inability to translate these measurements into human meaningful* time frames. Your total time for the SLOW query is only 1/3sec - has anyone actually noticed?

Comment: yep. It seems when I log onto the same network/server and run those queries, it's only differing by 1ms so it seems I need to just trust the numbers from EXPLAIN ANALYSE. It has to be something to do with pgAdmin

Comment: Hi @Intellix , I suggest you put your conclusion in an answer. It would make it easier for community users who have the same question to find the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the timings that I was using were from PgAdmin and after SSHing into the actual database network/server I can see that the difference was negligible between the two variants and it was actually the same as appears in the `EXPLAIN ANALYSE`.

So it's actually not quicker doing a UNION than the queries individually/

Answer (score 0):

You should use `UNION ALL`, which simply concatenates the results, instead of `UNION`, which *also* dedupes results, usually by sorting, to make a fair comparison.

Maybe the optimizer is confused and is using a different heuristic due to the presence of a dedupe operation and the small row count cause an edge case that doesn’t make sense.

Comment: `UNION ALL` is the same result. It's still 200ms quicker than making one of the queries alone. The time is the full round trip and I can see it in Chrome Network Requests as well. My concern is that all of my queries throughout my app are suffering from something strange

Comment: ok it seems pgAdmin takes much longer to fetch that result for some reason but if I connect to the same network it's within the milliseconds range so I guess the real timing is in the EXPLAIN ANALYSE response